# how can I handle inconsistent markup?

Tags: xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a project where I have to scrape many URLs from many pages. I thought the structure of every page would remain the same, but sometimes it changes and breaks my code.

I need to extract, for example, the abstract of an article and its keywords, both of which are in a separate `<p>` with the same class `"marginB3"`. So I scraped a page and only got two results, one for the abstract and the other one for the keywords:

```
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
lista =  hxs.select('//p[@class="marginB3"]/text()')  
self.abstracto = lista[0].extract()
self.keywords = lista[1].extract()
```

I then tried with a third page and a new `<p>` appeared with some additional information about the article and altered the structure. That made it more complicated since there are no ids and only classes. How can I differentiate which one is the `<p>` for the keywords without id's if they have their own `<h2>` above them:

```
<h2>Info</h2>
<p class="marginB3">a_url_I_want</p>
```

Can I do this differentiation by reading that `<h2>` and then the `<p>` below it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly can.

Try this:

```
# First <p>
hxs.select('//h2/following-sibling::p[@class="marginB3"][1]/text()').extract()
# Second <p>
hxs.select('//h2/following-sibling::p[@class="marginB3"][2]/text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an XPATH expert, but I think you need to look at the `following` axis to catch the items after the `<h2>` tag.

In general, XPATH does poorly when the document you are trying to parse isn't well marked. At the risk of adding even more complexity, you could look at something like the [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) module that would allow a more procedural way of coping with inconsistent markup. XPATH is a (mostly) declarative language and declarative languages have a hard time coping with non-regular input.